# Problem binding .IsSelected count of checkbox to Label WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new WPF and still am trying to get a grasp on MVVM bindings.

Basically I am trying to bind listofitems.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true).Count(); to a label where IsSelected represents the checkbox check.
And everytime the checkbox is unselected the label will update as well.

IsSelected is a property of Item class

```
XML

<Label x:Name="numeratorLbl" Content="{Binding Path=ItemList, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

```
Code Behind

        private bool mIsSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return mIsSelected;  }
            set
            {
                mIsSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");  
            }
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

public ObservableCollection<Item> listofitems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you also show how you define your `ItemList` property?

Comment: Have a separate property on your vm that gets that info. Then Bind to that. Also use TextBlock and delete that name of the control, It has zero use.

Comment: Just noticed why is your collection a static property?!

Comment: Sorry about the static property. Could you or anyone show me how to create the view model and which property I'm supposed to bind to?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate property which takes in status and returns the proper text depending on any/all logic or output text needed.

Use the other properties to do Notify changes on the aforementioned property. For example, everytime `IsSelected` is changed, it also changes the status of our new property `LabelStatus`. ***Also*** do that on all other logic related set properties:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return mIsSelected;  }
    set
    {
        mIsSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); 
        OnPropertyChanged("LabelStatus"); 
    }
}

public string LabelStatus 
{ 
    get { return IsSelected? listofitems.Where( ... ).Count() : "-"; } 
}
```

Then just bind to `LabelStatus` like  `Content="{Binding LabelStatus}" />`

---

I provide a more complete example on my blog:

[Xaml: MVVM Example for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)